# A quotient space that does not satisfy the first countability axiom

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X=\mathbb{N}\times I$, where $I=[0,1]$, $ \mathbb{N}$ has the
>   discrete topology  and $I$ has the induced topology from usual
>   $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the quotient space $X/\mathord\sim$ by the
>   relation $(n,0)\sim(m,0)$, $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that
>   $X/\mathord\sim$ does not satisfy the first countability axiom.

I can suppose that each $x \in X/\mathord\sim$ have a countable local basis, I know that the projection $\pi: X \rightarrow  X/\mathord\sim$ is continuous and onto. But basic sets don't go back into basics, bot only into open sets. The resulting space is like a sun, $\omega$ copies of $I$ joint by their $0$. I know that $\mathbb{N}\times I$ is first countable, since each factor is first countable, however I don't have a good idea of how to proceed on this. What can I do with this basis to reach a contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $p$ be the centre point of the ‘sun’. For each sequence $r=\langle r_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of positive real numbers let

$$B(r)=\{p\}\cup\{\langle n,x\rangle\in\Bbb N\times I:x<r_n\}\;.$$

First show that the collection of all such $B(r)$ is a local base at $p$. Now suppose that $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable local base at $p$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is a sequence $r^{(n)}=\langle r_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of positive real numbers such that $B(r^{(n)})\subseteq U_n$. Find a sequence $r=\langle r_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $B(r)\nsupseteq B(r^{(n)})$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. I’ve given a further hint for doing so in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Try to make $r$ ‘squeeze inside’ $r^{(n)}$ on it’s $n$-th coordinate.

Comment: I don't understand why should I prove that $B(r)\nsubseteq B(r^{(n)})$, shouldn't it be the other way? I have to construct a nbh that doesn't have inside any $U_n$, right?

Comment: Besides, what happens if the sequence $r^{(n)}$ converges to the point $p$? I couldn't find the $r$ that makes the $B(r)$ smaller! :(

Comment: @Hermine: Your first comment is absolutely right: I accidentally typed `\subseteq` instead of `\supseteq`. (I use it the former much more often, and my fingers have apparently learnt this too well!) Thanks for catching that. \\ Did you look at the further hint? For each $n\in\Bbb N$, it’s enough to get $r$ less than $r^{(n)}$ on **one** coordinate in order to ensure that $B(r)$ doesn’t contain $B(r^{(n)}$.